# Ansible flatten out a multi-tier list

Tags: list, ansible

In Ansible trying to parse a multi-level list and trying to figure how to flatten the list for ease of parsing (loop). My latest attempt was using a template but seems the end results Ansible does not recognize as a list. There maybe a better way of doing this.

```
the_list:
    [ 
    {
        "clusters": [ "host1", "host2" ],
        "space": "space1"
    },
    {
        "clusters": [ "host1", "host2" ],
        "space": "space2"
    }
    ]

template file:

    {%- for instance in the_list %}
    {%- for cluster in instance.clusters %}
    [ cluster: {{ cluster }}, namespace: {{ instance.space }} ]
    {%- endfor %}
    {%- endfor %}
```

Desired results:

namespace: space1, clusters: host1
namespace: space1, clusters: host2
namespace: space2, clusters: host1
namespace: space2, clusters: host2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your desired output, but this looks like a case where the [subelements filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_filter.html) would be useful:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    the_list:
        [ 
        {
            "clusters": [ "host1", "host2" ],
            "space": "space1"
        },
        {
            "clusters": [ "host1", "host2" ],
            "space": "space2"
        }
        ]

  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: report.txt
        content: |
          {% for data in the_list|subelements('clusters') %}
          namespace: {{ data.0.space }}, cluster: {{ data.1 }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Running the above playbook produces (in file `report.txt`):

```
namespace: space1, cluster: host1
namespace: space1, cluster: host2
namespace: space2, cluster: host1
namespace: space2, cluster: host2
```

Comment: I am using the list with a include_tasks and if the list is flatten be forehand it will be easier to process, I have tied other ways to do this but no luck. If I use jinja2 Ansible does not see it as a list., seems jinja2 might not be a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. **This** is using a jinja2 template and it happily sees a list. You could drop it straight into your `template_file`. Can you explain in more detail about what you want?